# Getting nil, null or unknown from SwiftyJSON

Tags: swift, swifty-json

```
{
    "locations": [
      {
         "id": "#######################",
         "slug": "some slug",
         "name": "some name",
         "address": "some address",
         "characteristic": false,
         "program_types": [
            "Program 1"
         ],
         "category 1": false,
         "category 2": true,
         "category 3": false,
         "category 4": 4,
         "category 6": 0,
         "latitude": #######,
         "longitude": -###.####
      },
   ]
}
```

Above is my JSON (only a single entry of many) that I want to use with SwiftyJSON.  I am using Alamofire to get the data and it shows up well when I println from Alamofire.

Here is the code that isn't working.  I've tried multiple things found on various websites.

```
var json = JSON(data!)  //data is from alamofire
let Name = json[0].string
println(Name)
```

returns `nil

This code returns `null`.

```
var json = JSON(data!)
let Name:JSON = json[0]["name"]
println(Name)
```

I'm not sure how to just return a simple value from the JSON.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `data!`?  "data not"? and given your structure, you'd probably want `json['locations'][0]['slug']` -> `some slug`.

Comment: @MarcB: `!` (in this context) is the "forced unwrapping operator" in the [Swift programming language](https://developer.apple.com/swift/).

Comment: what do you get when you `po data!`? and when you `po json`?

Comment: @MarcB That was it.  `let Name:JSON = json["locations"][0]["category"]` works.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

@marcB came up with the right answer.  It was simply an issue of improper order.

This code
`let Name:JSON = json[0]["name"]`

should be
`let Name:JSON = json["locations"][0]["category"]`

Answer (score 0):

Check the type of json[0]

My guess it would be AnyObject

What means you need to downcast it like this

```
Let Name = json[0] as! [String:NSDictionary]
```